# Align Haskell import statements in Vim using Tabular plugin?

Tags: haskell, vim, indentation, tabular, vim-tabular

I'd like to format Haskell import statements into style I usually see in published source code.

From this:

```
import Data.Map
import qualified Data.Vector as V
```

To this:

```
import           Data.Map
import qualified Data.Vector as V
```

I'd like to not have to install any plugins that specialize in just doing this. Just [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular). Could someone help me with the regexp needed to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to just align the first uppercase character so that they are on top of each other, this appears to work on your test case

```
:%Tabularize /\C[A-Z].*/
```

The `\C` forces case sensitive comparison.

Comment: Brilliant solution! Thanks.

Comment: You can also use `\u` instead the character class. Also if you want to have the aliases line up you can do something like this: `:Tabularize/\u\S\+/`

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a plugin for this; You could just run [stylish-haskell](https://github.com/jaspervdj/stylish-haskell) - or a similar code formatter, if there is one by now - on your source.